# How to access hadoop hdfs via URL and use in the program

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

My hadoop dfs is accessible via

`http://localhost:50075/browseDirectory.jsp?dir=%2Fuser%2Fhdone%2Ftext&namenodeInfoPort=50070`

In my program i have to replace the input with reference to my hdfs

`FileInputFormat.addInputPath(conf, new Path("input"));`

My core-site.xml has the value 
`hdfs://localhost:54310` which i can't access using the URL.

My actual hdfs path is `/users/hdone/text2` where all the files are located with appropriate permissions.

So what do I write for `input` ?

Comment: Can you try changing the port to 9000 and check? So it will be `hdfs://localhost:9000/users/hdone/text2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shall just give the dfs' relative path to your input and it shall be read correctly.

For example, you are creating an input path as follows:

```
$ hadoop fs -mkdir my_input_directory
$ hadoop fs -put /home/user/my-test-file.csv my_input_directory/my-test-file.csv
```

Now, in order to run your hadoop job, you may execute something like follows:

```
$ hadoop jar my_test_program.jar **my_input_directory** my_output_directory
```

And in your Java code, you may just access it via `args[0]`, like this:

```
FileInputFormat.addInputPath(conf, new Path(args[0]));
```